# Перевод exe в ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер

Чем сконвертировать `exe` и `dll` в ассемблерный код без запуска этих файлов? Есть ли возможность перевести в код на си?

Answer (score 4):

Ищите в гугле по ключевому слову декомпилятор (decompiler).
Сишный код генерит IDA Pro с плагином Hex Rays, только нет никаких гарантий того, что он будет компилироваться.

Comment: Хороший же ответ, зря удалили ) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/193820/181472